# Use case for NER libraries

Tags: stanford-nlp

Hi I am exploring NER libraries to parse through some financial documents, company filings - prospectus etc.

These documents have information like the company name - some keywords and a value associated with them.

I would like to tag and extract these as 3 different entities.

So say for instance I have a phrase or sentence that reads.
ABC corp submitted the following on 1/1/2017 ...We are offering $300,000,000 aggregate principal amount of Floating Rate Notes due 2014 (the “2014 Floating Rate Notes”), $400,000,000 aggregate principal amount of 2.100% Notes due 2014 (the “2014 Fixed Rate Notes”), $400,000,000 aggregate principal amount of 3.100% Notes due 2016 (the “2016 Notes”), and $400,000,000 aggregate principal amount of 4.625% Notes due 2021 (the “2021 Notes”).

I would like to tag ABC corp as organization. 
The principal aggregate amount as the key word and 
$400000000 as the number value.

I tried running some sample through http://corenlp.run/ it works great for the amounts the keywords and dates - however for the organization name I don't always have it tagged. IS this the standard use case for NER any idea as to why that might be the case for organization name.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the NER model should tag organizations in text.  Note that the model was trained on sentences that are different from your data, so performance will drop.  Also, the model does not have 100% recall so it will make mistakes from time to time.